# XSockets doesn't send while using SendToAllExcept

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, xsockets.net

I am using XSockets library in dotnet with a version > 3.0
Everything works fine for me except send to all except

```
this.SendToAllExcept(p => p.ClientGuid == target.ClientGuid, new { target }, "eventName");
```

I have tried almost all functions, they are all working for me except this .. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can confirm that it is a bug. You had some clever workaround using the SendTo with != instead of == to solve it. You can also use the Find<T>(Func<T,bool> expression) to get clients and then use SendToAllExcepts and pass in the clients you do not want to send to. That override should work. The bug is in the extension with the lambda expression.